# Global Elo leadeboard with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create elo based leaderboard from multiple tables. Table structures are shown down below. What I am looking for is query that would sum elo from all tables into one for every single player that is in any of the tables and then order it desc to get top 10 players with global elo.

players_mode_thebridges

| id | name | elo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JesusChrist69 | 13 |
| 2 | 62MB | 196 |

players_mode_sumo

| id | name | elo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JesusChrist69 | 196 |

players_mode_boxing

| id | name | elo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 62MB | 723 |

Does anyone know how to make that work? I am struggling on that problem for quite some time. All I was able to do was get global elo of one specific player but what I need is to get top 10 players. Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Have you had a crack at it yourself yet

Comment: UNION all tables, Group by and order by sum and limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `name`, SUM(elo) AS elo FROM
(SELECT `name`, `elo` FROM players_mode_boxing
UNION
SELECT `name`, `elo` FROM players_mode_sumo
UNION
SELECT `name`, `elo` FROM players_mode_thebridges) X
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `elo` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

How I was taught was to join the tables with the pairs for example **players_mode_sumo.id=players_mode_sumo.id** and a **descending order** of elo and a **limit of 10** plus I add all the elo

```
SELECT players_mode_sumo.id, players_mode_thebridges.name, SUM(players_mode_thebridges.elo)
FROM players_mode_sumo, players_mode_thebridges, players_mode_boxing 
WHERE players_mode_sumo.id=players_mode_sumo.id 
AND players_mode_sumo.id=players_mode_boxing.id 
ORDER BY elo DESC 
SUM(players_mode_thebridges.elo) 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1992) Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You also may wish to check that syntax

Comment: I'm sorry but I've been taught this way for a year now and I don't know how to use inner join so this is my way of helping you.

Comment: Whom so ever taught you to do this in the last year, should be seriously chastised and drummed out of the teaching proffession

Comment: but it still works?